# android changing text view (is this code ok?)

Tags: android, xml, textview

Can some one help me, I have heard alot of things and I dont know what to believe. I am making an app that is a counter. In my xml layout i have a TextView acting as a counter and the text is set by a string in strings.xml and i am controlling what the text view says from my java file. here is some code snip its. all I want to know is this ok?, it works fine but I want to know is it a bad or good way.

```
"counter" equals a variable.
"display" is referencing the ID of the textview"

what i am using to control the text view.
display.setText(String.valueOf(counter)); 

here is my text view in my xml layout
<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tvDisplay"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/counter"
    android:textSize="20dp" />

here is the string in strings.xml
<string name="counter">0</string>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, All things are right and good. Yo should have to give the String Value as like that.

If there is a Small Value of TextView then you can directly give as android:text="abcd"

And If you want to give any reference of that then your code is also correct and works as well.

For the Best use of coading your should have to try as like you have done rightnow. as Because it helps you a lot if there are number of TextView and you want to manage or change the Value of it quickly.

Enjoy.  :)

Thanks.

Comment: Okay, Thanks for your help and time i always like getting told that I'm on the right track. i would just like to ask you this if you wouldn't mind answering, as you say "If there is a Small Value of TextView then you can directly give as android:text="abcd" if i do that it flags up a warning so i just use a string variable, or is what you are trying to say is to ignore that warning because its harmless, and the way you're done things is okay so for best use just carry on as you are.? thank for you help.

Answer (score 2):

It's fine, that's how you change text dynamically.

Comment: Thanks, if you could answer this it would be great. would i use this "display.setText(String.valueOf(counter)); " for changing the text view to a number or value and i would use this "display.setText("text");" for setting it to q text or a string?

Comment: @JackTrowbridge As long as what you're calling the method with ends up being a string, you can set it to anything you want. You could also use display.setText("" + counter) for the number.